# Asp.net Core - How to InvokeAsync for a ViewComponent from javascript?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a simple ViewComponent (i.e. partialview) which i can do an InvokeAsyn() to render a small snippet of HTML by placing the invoke code within my CSHTML.

**Question**

How can I call a ViewComponent InvokeAsync (or any method) to retrieve raw data (not necessarily HTML markup) from javascript?

**Alternatively**

An alternative approach that could totally work is exposing an Asp.net Core API which i can simply call from javascript side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call view components using http(Ajax) but you can have action method on controller will can return view component  out put as resut

Comment: I do not have a Controller, per se. My project only has a Program.cs, Startup.cs, and Razor Pages.

Comment: i was able to add an API Controller. now im able to retrieve the sample/template data. I will try to make this get api return data which i am looking for. Thank you.